# Embedding strings inside a return statement using Python

Tags: python, string, return

I have some Python code that has a function I called getFormatted() that turns a date in the form of `month,date,year` (comma separated) into `MM/DD/YYYY`. I'd like `getFormatted()` to use a return statement so when you call it with `print(self.bdate.getFormatted())` it returns `MM/DD/YYYY`, but I can't figure out how to embed the `/`s. The best I can do is make `getFormatted()` produce a print statement and call it by just `self.bdate.getFormatted()`.

So, is there a way to embed strings in a return statement?

Comment: _"I have some Python code"_ - until you show it to us, this information is useless

Answer (score 1):

```
def getFormatted(month, day, year):
    # Your missing code here
    return "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(month, day, year)

print getFormatted(2, 2, 2012)
```

Comment: Or: `getFormatted = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format`

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? You can just return it.

```
def getDate():
    return "02/02/1993"
```

You should be able to simply replace `print` with `return` in your function